# Regular expressions in Mysql/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

I have a question on a regular expression wanting to use MySQL / phpMyAdmin. Is the next:

```
^ [^ 0-9] $
```

As it is to not return any tuple in the table containing numbers, but the problem is that returns a tuple with contains numbers. The full statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name REGEXP "^ [^ 0-9] $";
```

So I do not know what is the problem. Because I have two tuples that have real names and a "false" tuple it is pure numbers and returns that tuple sentence with numbers.

Note: the "name" column in the "person" table is varchar.

Comment: Try adding a + after the closing square bracket I.e `[^0-9]+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to return columns that don't have numbers, is that correct?

If so I think

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name not REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

would be the simplest approach.

Your regex currently looks for a column that has a leading whitespace, a non-number or whitespace, and then a white space to end.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b047/2

Comment: Thank you! It served me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name REGEXP '^[^0-9]+$'
```

You were close.[See fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b047/3/0)