# How to make this regex pattern work in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

I have the following regex:

```
[^A-Z0-9\.\s\%\$\/\-\+]
```

And I use it like below in PHP:

```
preg_match("/[^A-Z0-9\.\s\%\$\/\-\+]/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

But when I try to use the same regex in phpMyAdmin I get errors or it is not working as expected.

How should I alter it in order to make it work in MySQL syntax?

Comment: You should be able to use REGEX in your query. phpMyAdmin is just an interface for your database and you shouldn't be coding PHP there.

Comment: Well, it would help to see what you're trying and what the errors are.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have support for PCRE so you can't use the exact same regex. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html and here: http://www.regextester.com/eregsyntax.html

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I'm almost sure he is trying to use regex inside the query (and not as part of the php code).

Comment: I am too - but he hasn't shown us that @Dekel

Comment: @Dekel exactly, i need a regex only, a 1- 1 representation, of what works in php code, how it should be altered, in order to work in MySQL

Comment: Add the exact query you are trying to run (and note that it's not related at all to phpmyadmin - the question is about mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this user posted:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name not REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

From here [Regular expressions in Mysql/phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292716/regular-expressions-in-mysql-phpmyadmin)

phpmyadmin would use database syntax not php code, Examples:

PHP Syntax (how you would use a regex in PHP)

`$regex = "/[^A-Z0-9\.\s\%\$\/\-\+]/";
preg_match($regex, $input_line, $output_array);`

SQL Syntax (what you would use to query a SQL database like MySQL)

`SELECT * FROM person WHERE name not REGEXP '[0-9]'`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "database syntax not php". That sentence doesn't really makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

`\s` (and several other `\` things) are not implemented by MySQL's regexp.  In its place, use `[:SPACE:]`.